# Cannot locate csv file when the trigger comes from the frontend with django

Tags: python, django, pandas, csv

In a few words, I want the user to give a text input at a frontend form in order to define the dataset that wants to examine, for instance 'data.csv'.
This 'data.csv' is passed as a string variable to a python function that needs to open the dataframe with the specific name. The error is:

```
FileNotFoundError at /
[Errno 2] File b'data.csv' does not exist: b'data.csv'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] File b'data.csv' does not exist: b'data.csv'
```

The file data.csv is in the same directory with the file beta.py that calls the file in order to read it.
Moreover, if I don't pass any value from the frontend side, but I just trigger the script, and instead of `dataframe = pd.read_csv(file)`, I have `dataframe = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`, it gives me the same error, but if i execute the script from the command line, then everything runs just fine. So I can't figure why the script cannot locate data.csv if the trigger comes from the frontend.

These are the codes.
PS: Thank you all in advance so much for the help

**views.py**

```
def get_name(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NameForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        file = form.cleaned_data.get('your_name')
        beta.hello(file)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

# if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
  else:
    form = NameForm()

return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

**beta.py**

```
import pandas as pd

def hello(file):
   dataframe = pd.read_csv(file)
```

**home.html**

```
    <form action="/" method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
          <input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name">
          <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
```

UPDATE:

```
def hello(s):
    file = 'data.csv'.encode("utf-8")
    print(type(file))
    #dataframe = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str(s)))
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(file))
    print("---")
    print(dataframe)




*** Results ***
<class 'str'>
<class 'bytes'>
---
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [data.csv]
Index: []
```

Comment: Did you try decoding the bytestring first? `file = file.decode("utf-8")`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. It's a string and the string object has not attribute 'decode'. This is the error:
AttributeError at /
'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: I just checked and Python doesn't seem to care if the file name is a bytestring, so it can't be that.

Comment: The strange thing that appears is the letter 'b' before my file name.

b'data.csv' does not exist: b'data.csv'

Comment: Yes, that's why I thought a bytestring might be the problem - it doesn't display like that on my traceback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost always a good idea to build absolute paths in Django, as you're never sure of the interpreter's location at the time of execution. In your case, django is most likely looking for data.csv in your project's base directory and not where your views.py is located.

```
import pandas as pd
from django.conf import settings

def hello(file):
    print(settings.BASE_DIR)
    fpath = os.path.join(
        settings.BASE_DIR,
        'appname',
        file
    )
    dataframe = pd.read_csv(fpath)
```

If that doesn't work, BASE_DIR is probably pointing to projectname/projectname/ (check the printed output from hello()). Create a new variable in settings.py and use that instead of BASE_DIR (this happens in my case for some reason):

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(settings.TOP_DIR,...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TOP_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
```

Comment: Yes, but when I execute the file within PyCharm's terminal, it can read the file just as fine. Is this different than Django's execution?

Comment: No worries! Yes, if you want to test modules in your django app, run `python manage.py shell` and then import the module that you want to test: `from myapp.beta import hello` This allows you to run the code in the context of the django app which is extremely useful.